# How to extend a class and ignore the pseudoclass in Sass

Tags: sass

Is it possible in Sass to `@extend` a class and to not include some pseudoclass.

for instance:

```
&.sprite-icon-thumbs-up {
    @include sprite(-130px, -239px, 51px, 22px);
}

&.sprite-icon-thumbs-up:hover {
    @include sprite(-185px, -239px, 51px, 22px);
}
```

later on I include `@extend` the sprite:

```
.some-class {
    @extend .sprite;
    @extend .sprite-icon-thumbs-up;

    &.disabled {
        // here I would need it to override the hover so that when disabled I don't get the :hover sprite but I still get the normal sprite.
    }
}
```

My first thought was to do something like:

```
    &.disabled:hover {
        @extend .sprite-icon-thumbs-up;  // But exclude the :hover from the extend
    }
```

my *HTML* code is a simple as:

```
<span class="sprite sprite-icon-thumbs-up"></span>
```

Is there some way to do that in Sass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `@extend` a selector, you extend *every* instance of it.  That includes matching pseudoclasses (`.foo:before`) and compound selectors (`.bar .foo .baz`).

If this is not the behavior you want, then you will need to create an additional selector to extend from:

```
.sprite {
    // stuff
}

%foo, .sprite-icon-thumbs-up {
    @include sprite(-130px, -239px, 51px, 22px);
}

.sprite-icon-thumbs-up:hover {
    @include sprite(-185px, -239px, 51px, 22px);
}

.some-class {
    @extend .sprite;
    @extend %foo;
}
```

Comment: Nice & clean solution, gj

Comment: Sounds like a nice workaround, will keep in mind. I chose a not so good but really clean approach... I introduced the sprite twice :)
In my case was ok since it's really small and was already empty space on the png :D

Answer (score 1):

You can't exclude the pseudo classes but you can use a mixin instead: Look the following example:

```
@mixin sprite($pseudo: true) {
  background: red;

  @if $pseudo == true {
     &:hover {
      background: blue;
    } 
  }
}

.sprite {
  @include sprite(true);
}

.some-class {
  @include sprite(false);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
.sprite {
  background: red;
}
.sprite:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.some-class {
  background: red;
}
```

An example : http://sassmeister.com/gist/1addc4ddc0c8111835ea

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its possible. You might just have to overwrite your styles:

```
.some-class {
    @extend .sprite;
    @extend .sprite-icon-thumbs-up;

    &.disabled {
        // here I would need it to override the hover so that when disabled I don't get the :hover sprite but I still get the normal sprite.
        &:hover {
            // Overwrite extended hover styles here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was my first try, does not work though.

Comment: If you're simply overwriting the styles, what doesn't work?