# SASS: Extra selectors added from extended class?

Tags: sass

I am attempting to use a modernizr class with an extended class. I have the following SCSS code:

```
%some-extended-class {
    color:red;
}
.no-csstransforms %some-extended-class {
    color:blue;
}

.class-one {
    .class-two {
        .class-three {
            @extend %some-extended-class;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the two extended class declarations; the second is preceded by the `.no-csstransforms` modernizr class. This is what I would **expect** to get:

```
.class-one .class-two .class-three {
  color: red;
}

.no-csstransforms .class-one .class-two .class-three {
  color: blue;
}
```

However, this is the output I am getting:

```
.class-one .class-two .class-three {
  color: red;
}

.no-csstransforms .class-one .class-two .class-three, .class-one .class-two .no-csstransforms .class-three {
  color: blue;
}
```

Note the extra `.class-one .class-two .no-csstransforms .class-three`, which is unnecessary, and I don't understand why it is being added?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extend a class and ignore the pseudoclass in Sass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990839/how-to-extend-a-class-and-ignore-the-pseudoclass-in-sass)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. I'm not talking about pseudoclasses. I want to know what is causing the behaviour I demonstrated in my question. The accepted answer you linked to states "When you @extend a selector, you extend every instance of it. That includes [...] compound selectors (.bar .foo .baz)." But that doesn't seem to explain why I would get `.class-one .class-two .no-csstransforms .class-three` in my output? Why does the `.no-csstransforms` class insert itelf in the third position in that heirarchy?